# How effective is invisible reCAPTCHA on react-native?

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, invisible-recaptcha

We have a use case where we need to protect a login/sign up endpoint from bad actor. This endpoint is expensive for us, because we need to send a One Time Password (OTP) to the submitted number.

A few prevention already in place, such as:

1. IP rate limiting
2. Phone number prefix check. They usually call the endpoint with number in sequence.
3. Only enable "Resend" button in the mobile app after 60 seconds & gradually increase.

This bad actors still find a way to pass our check. We want to introduce captcha challenge on our mobile app. [reCAPTCHA v3](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3) looks promising since it does not sacrifice user experience on the app.

Our app is written in react native & need to support both iOS & Android. So we must integrate it to our app by calling WebView.

Is this captcha effective enough to detect BOT, since there is not much interaction in the web view?

Comment: _"because we need to send a One Time Password (OTP) to the submitted number."_ - [uughhhh](https://blog.sucuri.net/2020/01/why-2fa-sms-is-a-bad-idea.html) - you do know [that SMS-based](https://www.theregister.com/2016/12/06/2fa_missed_warning/) 2FA [is insecure](https://securityboulevard.com/2021/12/why-using-sms-authentication-for-2fa-is-not-secure/), right? Do you support TOTP? If not, **why not**?

Comment: _"Our app is written in react native [../] so we must integrate it to our app by calling WebView."_ - eh? the whole point of React Native is use native widgets instead of WebViews for a better UX...